# Robot to forward massage from channel to user

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I wrote a Telegram bot. I ran into a problem with the Telebot library somewhere at work. I want to use a channel to store my files so that the user can quickly download any file he wants and not upload it.
For example, if he wants a certain movie, he can quickly download it.
Please send me a sample so that I can use it as a sample for my bot.

I write many codes to forward messages from channel A to channel B but I have a problem in forwarding to users who use my bot.

Comment: and we have problem to see your code. If you get error message then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image), And show code which makes this problem.